# Making phone call from mobile web browser

Tags: html, mobile

I am just thinking, is there any possibility to make call to the mobile from a mobile webpage link (from mobile bowser).

```
<p>Making call from webpage.</p>
<a href='#' id='contact'>contact: 97080 18380</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make use of the [tel protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme):

```
<p>Making call from webpage.</p>
<a href='tel:9708018380' id='contact'>contact: 97080 18380</a>
```

Plus, check [mobilexweb](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/click-to-call-links-mobile-browsers) for some nice tips about that matter.

Answer (score 3):

An internet search told me this:

```
<p>Making call from webpage.</p>
<a href='tel: 97080 18380' id='contact'>contact: 97080 18380</a>
```

http://demosthenes.info/blog/536/Adding-Phone-Numbers-To-Web-Pages-With-HTML5-&-Microdata